# Can I invoke controller outside Flask server startup?

Tags: python, flask, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to create a simple model view controller pattern using Python and Flask. I add a new controller but it appears the routes are not being invoked.

server.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    TicTacToeController()

    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

This class is defined in a new file:

```
class TicTacToeController :

    @app.route('/ttt')
    def ttt(self):
       return render_template('home-tic-tac-toe.html')
```

Error when try to visit route '/ttt':

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

Defining `@app.route('/ttt')` in server.py the route `'/'` is accessible. How to add the controller mappings in a new class that is separate to the main server class ( `server.py` ) ?

Answer (score 0):

All your functions with `@app.route` need to be defined before calling `app.run`. Once you call `app.run` that line will run forever as it's now serving requests. Put it at the bottom.

You also don't need to put your routes inside classes. Just `def ttt():` at the global level.

Comment: thanks, app.run is defined at the global level. TicTacToeController is defined in a separate class (ive updated question) so the routes should be invoked prior to run being called.